# Lvalue issues in increment Operators

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char a[]="Hello";
  char *p=a;
  while(*p)
    ++*p++;     //Statement 2
    printf("%s",a);
    int x=10;
    ++x++; //Statement 1
   return 0;
}
```

When i compile this code i get an l-value Required error in Statement 1, which i can understand. How is that statement 2 does not produce an error even though i intend to do the same thing? Can someone shed light?

Comment: p is modified twice between sequence points so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin No, it isn't. `++*p++` is `++(*(p++))`, `p` is modified only once, no UB.

Comment: Ok, one question: WHY do you want to write such a code, without brackets? use proper brackets & the behaviour would be predictable + readable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops I meant x. ++x++ is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin It would be if it compiled, indeed.

Comment: @Lundin: `++x++` is a constraint violation, not UB.

Answer (score 3):

Both pre-increment and post-increment produce rvalues and rvalues can't be modified.

So `++x++` (statement 1) is clearly a constraint violation and compiler gives error.

But it's not the case with the statement 2. Though `p++` produces an rvalue which its value can't be modified, it can be *dereferenced*. Alternatively if you do `++p++` this would be equivalent to the `++x++` case and would give an error. Because here the pointer itself is modified.

So it's equivalent to: `++(*p++)`.

*(Note that the brackets are only for understanding and it's not required. The expression `++*p++` is well-defined.)*

What happens is:

- The post-increment `p++` evaluates to the old value of `p`, in this example `&a[0]`, and the stored value of `p` is incremented.
- `*p++` gives the value `p` pointed to before the increment, in this example `a[0]`.
- The final pre-increment increments that value, so `a[0]` becomes `I` (probably, could be something else on EBCDIC machines).

When the incremented values of `p` and `a[0]` are stored is unspecified, but both must have been stored at the next sequence point (the terminating `;`).

Comment: You have a bad formulation with "which was dereferenced by the post-increment". I know you mean the correct thing, and I don't know how to put it well, but that reads wrong. (I upvote in anticipation of an improved formulation.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I was kind of felt that when I wrote it. Not really sure how to re-word it. Does it look better?

Comment: I have tried to explain it better, if you don't like it at all, roll back.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Looks much clearer than what I had. Never thought writing the expression `++*p++` in plain English would be so hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from ISO C99 standard :

```
6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators
```

`Constraints

1

The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have qualified or
unqualified real or pointer type and shall be a modifiable lvalue.`

For this case :

```
++*p++;     //Statement 2
```

postfix `++` has higher precedence and prefix `++` and `*` has same precedence and `right to left` associativity. It means at first step it's incrementing the pointer not it's value.
So it will give you the next address of that `type`. And then `value (which is actually *p)` is incremented. So ,In this case no  `constraint violation`.
It's same as `++(*(p++))`.

For other case below:

```
 int x=10;
 ++x++; //Statement 1
```

In the above case of variable(not pointer) `++`(Either postfix or prefix increment or decrement) give you the `rvalue` ,then applying `++` or `--` on `rvalue` is `constraint violation`.`++` or `--` operand should be an `lvalue` . See the Standard quote written above. Hence giving error.

Comment: Postfix ++  has higher precedence than unary * and prefix ++ both. You seem to have confused this. No matter, the code is undefined behavior, so it doesn't fill any purpose trying to figure out what it will do.

Comment: @Lundin : Don't pretty sure about undefined behavior but `++` and `*` has same precedence...

Comment: @Lundin : The C programming by `K & R` in chapter 2 `2.12 Precedence and Order of Evaluation` see the table of operators given.And  what the problem with `++(*(p++))` expression , can you please explain ?

Comment: You have 3 different operators, postfix ++, prefix ++ and unary *. Their precedence is specified in C11 6.5/3: `The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax`. This means, the order of operator appearance in the C standard chapter 6.5 states the operator's precedence. Postfix ++ appears in 6.5.2 so it has higher precedence than prefix ++ and unary *, the latter two appear in 6.5.3 and have the same precedence, but are evaluated right-to-left in relation to each other.

Comment: `++(*(p++))` : p++ the next address, then `*(p++)` will be the value of that address and then `++(*(p++))` will give you the incremented value. I have parsed like this , Am I wrong ?

Comment: "value( which is `*p`) at that new address", no it's `*p` at the **old** address. `p++` evaluates to the not-incremented pointer.

Comment: @Omkant The precedence table in K&R is plain wrong, it is known to be one of the greatest errors in that book (that saying a lot, since there are so many errors in it).

Comment: @Omkant And yes, you are wrong, p++ will increment p to the next address, but only at the end of the expression (even though it is evaluated first). *p++ will be the value of the address before p++ is evaluated. And then ++*p will increase that value.

Comment: @Lundin : Thanks I corrected that. Can you please tell me about where is it saying that K&R table is wrong ? No offence , Just wanted for future reference.Is it corrected in next edition of this book ? I am still referring that book for C language. One more Personal query - Which book or reference should I prefer other than ISO C-standard or standard itself is enough ?

Comment: The C standard says that postfix operators have higher precedence than unary (prefix) operators, which in turn have higher priority than the cast operator. But K&R say that they are all the same, which is plain wrong.

Comment: I have no book recommendations. The standard is of course canon, if you can cope with the technical, complex reading. There's a [book recommendation list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on SO. I would particularly stay away from K&R, Programmming Pearls and anything written by Schildt.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char a[]="Hello";
  char *p=a;
  while(*p)
    ++*p++;     //Statement 2
    printf("%s",a);
    int x=10;
    ++x=x++; //Statement 1
   return 0;
}
```

//this  code will fetch same error due to the simultaneous pre and post increment.
because it cannot assign and increment simultaneously it require a value to perform increment on it.